# Как при наведении на родителя добавить класс ребенку?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как при наведении на родителя добавить класс ребенку?

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если действительно нужно именно добавить класс - то как то так, при помощи событий `mouseover` и `mouseout`:

```
let p = document.querySelector(".parent");
let c = document.querySelectorAll(".child");
p.addEventListener('mouseover', e => c.forEach(a => a.classList.add("hover")));
p.addEventListener('mouseout', e => c.forEach(a => a.classList.remove("hover")));
```

```js
let p = document.querySelector(".parent");
let c = document.querySelectorAll(".child");
p.addEventListener('mouseover', e => c.forEach(a => a.classList.add("hover")));
p.addEventListener('mouseout', e => c.forEach(a => a.classList.remove("hover")));
```

```css
.parent {
  width:300px;
  height:150px;
  border:solid;
}

.child {
  margin:33px;
  width:30px;
  height:30px;
  background-color:wheat;
  transition:1s;
  display:inline-block;
}

.hover {
  transform:rotate(45deg);
  border-radius:50%;
  background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

---

Но если нужно просто применить другой стиль, то можно и `css` ом обойтись:

```
.parent:hover .child {
  background-color:red;
}
```

```css
.parent {
  width:300px;
  height:150px;
  border:solid;
}

.child {
  margin:33px;
  width:30px;
  height:30px;
  background-color:wheat;
  transition:1s;
  display:inline-block;
}

.parent:hover .child{
  transform:rotate(45deg);
  border-radius:50%;
  background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

код выше сработает на потомке любой вложенности с классом `.child`, если необходим потомок только первого уровня можно написать так:

```
div.parent:hover > .child {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('.parent').hover(function() {
  $(this).find('.child').css('background-color', '#f00');
}, function() {
  $(this).find('.child').css('background-color', '#e2e2e2');
});
```

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 15px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.parent {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: #e2e2e2;
}

.child {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="parent">
    <div class="child"></div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```